# Question about Constructible Points

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometric-construction

A point $P$ is constructible from $\{ O , I \}$ [that is, from $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$] iff $P$ is constructible from $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$.

I am confused on where to go with this. Should I be trying to use fields to do this or am I overthinking the problem? Thank you!

Comment: If a point can be constructed from $\{O,I\}$ then it can be constructed from $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, just because you have more points to work with. To do the converse, prove that from $\{O,I\}$ you can construct all points in $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$. To do this show that you multiply and interval by any integer (just repeat it the right number of times using the compass) and that you can divide an interval by any integer (use [Thales theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem)). Finally to get to all points in the plane, show that you can lift a perpendicular.

Comment: Actually, the Wikipedia article already has [the division of the interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem#Dividing_a_line_segment_in_a_given_ratio) written in it.